# Can a subset of indexes of a partial recursive function be recursively enumerable but not recursive?

Tags: computability

Consider a Gödelian numbering of partial recursive functions. Consider the set of indexes corresponding to some function $\phi$. It may be seen that this set is not recursively enumerable. Does this set contain a recursively enumerable non-recursive subset?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is yes, but please check critically. One can easily construct an infinite recursive set of indices of $\phi$ (adding "comments" to a program). From this infinite recursive set one can pick out a non recursively enumerable subset.

Comment: Yes - this is basically the padding lemma (not to be confused with the [padding argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument)).